# VB.NET Need guide on error checking using MessageBox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, error-handling, visual-studio-2015, messagebox

Lets say I have a form with 100 textboxes, comboboxes and other controls and I want to check if any of the controls is empty. When I click on 'OK' button, I want the messagebox to show a list of errors example Textbox1 is empty, Textbox30 is empty and such.

I can achieve this by doing the tedious method where I check textbox1 and messagebox is shown, check textbox2 and messagebox is shown again and so on.

I want the messagebox to show only once. How can I achieve this?

What I have did is that I set up an array and store all the error messages to be shown later by selecting (example Msgbox(errMessages(3) + Environment.newline + errMessages(30)) and I know this is not the right way to do it as well.

Please and thank you in advance.

Comment: Be nice to the user: look at the ErrorProvider component

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for the suggestion. But I want it to display in MessageBox. Possible?

Comment: If course it is possible, just accumulate the error msgs into one string

Comment: @Plutonix Well, that is the problem here. I am not sure how do I accumulate it. Any guides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct answer to your question:

You can store the empty controls in a list, and at the end create the message like this:

```
Dim empty_controls = New List(Of Control)

If TextBox1.Text = String.Empty Then
    empty_controls.Add(TextBox1)
End If

If TextBox2.Text = String.Empty Then
    empty_controls.Add(TextBox2)
End If

Dim result As String = String.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    empty_controls.Select(Function(c As Control) c.Name + " is empty"))

MessageBox.Show(result)
```

Here is even a better way to detect which text boxes are empty:

```
Dim empty_controls = New List(Of Control)

//The following line will search through all text boxes on the form
empty_controls.AddRange(
    Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(c As Control) c.Text = String.Empty))

//Here you can add other kinds of controls with their own way of determining if they are empty

Dim result As String = String.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    empty_controls.Select(Function(c As Control) c.Name + " is empty"))

MessageBox.Show(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed!